# Nodejs process not responding after sometime

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc

I am testing [node-webrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc) project on 16 core cpu and 32 GB RAM.
I started process with pm2 and after some time node process stop responding.
Url returns not reachable, video streaming stopped.

What i noticed:

1) Every time it stopped at memory consumption 3.5 GB , CPU 900% but i tried to increase old memory size to 24 GB then it failed randomly after reaching 9 GB Memory and 1100 cpu..

2) In pm2 logs i found

"(node:3397) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 newBroadcast listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit" but process keep running after this warning..

A) not sure this is memory leakage issue?

B) cpu consumption (900% out of 1600%) as i know node is single thread process so is there any chance thread assign to main node process reached to their peak point?

Please any suggestion how i can debug it..

concurrent users that time are around 110-120

Comment: Usually this is a sign of two things: 1) A resource leak somewhere (socket, file handle or other system resource) and 2) Poor error handling in your code that doesn't log when there are errors with such resources.

Comment: The MaxListenersExceededWarning warning is sometimes the sign of an actual bug and sometimes not as there are legitimate uses for having more than 10 listeners for the same event, but most of the time, it is a bug.  I would generally just cause a memory leak, but it doesn't sound like a memory leak is your main problem.  If you ran out of memory, node.js would crash, not stop responding.

Comment: The 900% CPU sounds pretty suspicious like you got caught in some infinite loop and you're never allowing the event loop to process any more events.  And, that would line up perfectly with the description that it just "stops responding".

Comment: Usually, the top two choices here are to 1) add lots more error handling and logging about what the server is doing so when it stops responding, you can see what it last did or what it's stuck on and 2) major code inspection to see where you could possibly get stuck in a loop.

Comment: About cpu usage i think it is due to video streaming (webrtc), i noted that it increase  7-8% with every one user connected to stream.

Comment: @jfriend00 i started the node process with PM2. is it possible pm2 is reason of memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was server outbound bandwidth.
Server has maximum uplink speed 128 MB/s (~1 Gbps) and stream consuming maximum allowed bandwidth and after that connection to server goes unreachable... 
It fixed by swtcihing our server to 500 MB/s bandwidth..